# ¿Cómo recorro un directorio de forma recursiva?

Tags: c, recursión

Llevo más de un día intentando arreglar un error en tiempo de ejecución, no le veo el sentido de que salga mal pues no veo posibles fallos de lógica en el código en C.

El problema es que tengo que recorrer un árbol de directorios recursivamente, listar todo lo que tope en el proceso y decir si es un directorio o un archivo. Todo está bien hasta el primer nivel de subdirectorios, pero después de ese, a todo subdirectorio que encuentra lo califica como archivo.

En tanto al directorio raíz, debo empezar en el directorio en el que se encuentre el archivo .c actualmente, así que no hay que usar argumentos en el main.

Lo que se me ocurre es que algo va mal en la recursividad o cuando califica a los primeros subdirectorios que hace que no reconozca a sus subdirectorios correctamente.

Adjunto mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

void recorrer(struct dirent*);
void buscar(struct dirent*);

void main()
{
    DIR *d = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *de = readdir(d);
    recorrer(de);
}

void recorrer(struct dirent *actual)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", actual->d_name);
    DIR *a = opendir(actual->d_name); //Intenta abrirlo como un directorio
    if(a) //Lo hizo
    {
        printf("Es un directorio\n");
        struct dirent *dir = readdir(a);
        while(dir != NULL) //Para seguir con la recursividad
        {
            if((strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0))
                //No vuelve a comenzar la recursividad si es el drectorio actual o el anterior
                recorrer(dir);
            dir = readdir(a);
        }
    }
    else //No pudo hacerlo
    {
        printf("Es un archivo\n");
        //buscar(actual);
    }
    closedir(a);
}
```

buscar es una función que usaré luego, así que favor ignorarla.

Ya he intentado recorrer los directorios de formas distintas, ya he hecho el mismo trabajo de tres maneras y el error persiste. Intenté usar el nombre del directorio como parámetro en lugar del dirent y trabajar con eso, también probé usar la librería sys/stat con sus funciones stat() y S_ISDIR(), ambas acabaron en lo mismo, así que prefiero pedir ayuda para arreglar la versión original (el código que compartí).

Pondré el árbol de directorios del lugar donde está el archivo .c por si ayuda a aclarar lo que pasa (los que tienen c son carpetas, los de a son archivos):

- c1

  - c3

    - a6
  - a2
  - a3
- c2

  - a4
  - a5
- a1

Con c1, c2 y a1 todo bien, pero todo lo que contienen c1 y c2 lo pone como archivo, y como c3 lo interpreta como archivo ni siquiera recorre a6

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estas aplicando mal la recursividad tambien puedes probar con estos cambios.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

void recorrer(DIR *d);
void buscar(struct dirent*);

void main()
{
    DIR *d = opendir(".");

    recorrer(d);
}

void recorrer(DIR *d)
{   
    struct dirent *actual = readdir(d);


    while(actual != NULL){

        if((strcmp(actual->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(actual->d_name, "..") != 0)){
            printf("\n%s\n", actual->d_name);
            DIR *siguiente = opendir(actual->d_name); //Intenta abrirlo como un directorio

            if(siguiente != NULL){
                //es directorio
                printf("es un directorio\n");
                recorrer(siguiente);
            }else{
                //es archivo
                printf("es un archivo\n");
            }
        }

        actual = readdir(d);
    }

    closedir(d);

}
```

Comment: Probé los cambios y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

Comment: El problema es que con el codigo anterior, solo puedes abrir directorios y archivos del **primer** nivel, para abrir archivos o directorios de segundo o **n** nivel debes pasarle la ruta completa cuando usas opendir. Puedes leer los codigos de errores que se devuelven cuando abres archivos [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html], [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html]lee acerca de los errores establecidos en **errno**. En pocas palabras lo que le falta al codigo es manejar paths no solo nombre de archivos\directorios.

Comment: Efectivamente pasar la ruta completa resolvió el problema. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si a tu función `recorrer( )` le pasas una `dirent *`, **no puedes recorrer el directorio inicial**. Tendrías que, o bien cambiar el `main( )`, o bien cambiar completamente tu `recorrer( )` para que acepte un `DIR *`, y así poder recorrer ese primer directorio, en el que arrancas.

He optado por la segunda opción, ya que la primera llevaría a duplicar código (en `main( )` y en `recorrer( )`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

void recorrer( DIR * );
void buscar( struct dirent* );

int main( ) {
  recorrer( opendir( "." ) );

  return 0;
}

void recorrer( DIR *actual ) {
  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dir;

  while( ( entry = readdir( actual ) ) ) {
    printf( "\n%s\n", entry->d_name );

    if( !( strcmp( entry->d_name, "." ) && strcmp( entry->d_name, ".." ) ) )
      continue;

    dir = opendir( entry->d_name );

    if( dir ) {
      printf( "Es un directorio\n" );
      recorrer( dir );
      closedir( dir );
    } else {
      printf("Es un archivo\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: La parte del `continue` por alguna razón no funciona y crea un bucle infinito, al arreglar eso termino con el mismo error que puse al inicio. Después probé hacer la función desde cero tal como usted lo puso (nuevamente cambiando el `continue`) y solo imprime el nombre de lo que contiene el fichero original. Adicionalmente, si arreglo la condición que tiene los `strcmp()` acabo nuevamente en el problema del principio

Comment: @Karman *Despite* mio, ya corregido. En el `if( !( strcmp( ...`, **hay que cambiar** `||` por `&&`. El duende del teclado, que estaba ese dia *bromista*.